# Anchor element works but button does not in Blazor client side

Tags: html, blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm new to Blazor and I am working on an example app (Blazing Pizza) in the [blazor-workshop on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop).
In one step of the tutorial, a button is used to go to another page

```html
<button href="checkout">Order</button>
```

This wasn't working so I tried to change from a button to an anchor, which did work:

```html
<a href="checkout">Order</a>
```

The blazor is running client side.

Can anyone explain why the button did not work, but the anchor did?
I'm also new to HTML so it could be something quite basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) documentation. `href` isn't a valid attribute for it. Generally, `button` elements are used to submit a form or have an [Event Handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) attached to them to "do the thing" when they are clicked.

The standard "click to go elsewhere", as you've discovered, is the [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) anchor element, which *does* natively support the `href` attribute.

You can't just stick any attribute in any element and except it to behave the same by default. For styling purposes, you'll need to use some CSS to get your link to look more like a button. This is also intrinsic to HTML in general, and doesn't really have anything to do with blazor.

Comment: I've only done C#/WPF/WinForms (a lot of it), so the hardest part about Blazor for me so far is learning HTML. I'm surprised there is no error checking in the editor, builder or even in the browser console when using an invalid attribute for an HTML element.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Blazor specifically - but in general HTML degrades nicely and quietly for the most part. And no error would be present because you can have any arbitrary attributes in HTML elements that you want (though for technical validation, you would want to add `data-` as a prefix to it). `<button data-button-attribute="value" href="#"></button>` is perfectly valid (though tehcnically the href won't validate without a `data-` prefix. Those two arbitrary attributes just need to be handled by you however you see fit. It's not so much "invalid" as much as they are "arbitrary".